# Django form data modification with jquery

Tags: python, jquery, django

I am trying to adapt an already working application in Django, but I am quite new to this environment and I am not the original developer so I may have some conceptual errors, but I have not found a way to solve the problem.

I have a django model which references a client list:

```py
clients = models.ManyToManyField(
    Client,
    blank=True,
    verbose_name=_('Clients'),
    related_name='clients',
)
```

It is being feed in the admin using the autocomplete feature, obtaining the client data from the other table. This is working perfectly.

I want to preload some data based on a select dropbox I have included in the form. On change of the select box, I want to include some values on this manytomany field.

I am using jquery to add values to the field, and as far as I have found, I need to add the client references in two places:

Add the name and the Id in a Select

```html
<select name="clients" id="id_clients" class="admin-autocomplete select2-hidden-accessible"
        data-ajax--cache="true" data-ajax--type="GET" data-ajax--url="/en/admin/client/client/autocomplete/"
        data-theme="admin-autocomplete" data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder=""
        multiple="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="2355">Client1</option>
</select>
```

Add the name in the unordered list (ul) as a new li.

```html
    <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
        <span class="select2-selection__clear">×</span>
        <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Client1">
            <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
            Client1
        </li>
        <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
            <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0"
                   autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"
                   spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list"
                   placeholder=""  style="width: 0.75em;">
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I have the jquery script trying to add this but I have not managed to make it work. The code (simplified version) is this one:

```js
    function addAll() {
        r=$("ul.select2-selection__rendered").empty();
        r=$('#id_clients').empty();
        stDel='<span class="select2-selection__clear">×</span>';
        r=$("span.select2-selection select2-selection--multiple").append(stDel);
        stClientList='<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Client1"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Client1</li>';
        r=$("span.select2-selection select2-selection--multiple").append(stClientList);
        stClientId='<option value="2355">Client1</option>';
        r=$('#id_clients').append(stClientId);
      }
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#id_language').change(function(){
          l=$('#id_language').val();
          if(l=="ES"){
            addAll();
          }
        });
      });
```

If I use this code the select part is correctly added, but not the ul/li part. If I just run the ul/li part it is added to the field but it is not able to store it. I am not sure which is the correcto way to add values to a field like this. Any ideas or corrections are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually create `li` tags they are automatically created by `select2` plugin whenever any value is selected .So, you just need to append new option inside your select-box then use `$("#id_clients").val('somevalue')`  to set value as selected this will make entry inside `ul` tag and lastly use `trigger('change')` to refresh your selectbox.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".select2-hidden-accessible").select2({
  width: '100px'
});

function addAll() {
  $('#id_clients').empty(); //empty select
  stClientId = '<option value="255">Client5</option>';
  $('#id_clients').append(stClientId); //append option
  $("#id_clients").val('255'); //set new value
  $("#id_clients").trigger('change'); //refresh select
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_language').change(function() {
    l = $('#id_language').val();
    if (l == "ES") {
      addAll();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select name="clients" id="id_language">
  <option value="li">li</option>
  <option value="ES">ES</option>
</select>
<select name="clients" id="id_clients" multiple="" class="admin-autocomplete select2-hidden-accessible">
  <option value="2355">Client1</option>
  <option value="23525">Client2</option>
</select>
```